# Android: obfuscating resources in HelloWorld

Tags: android, proguard, android-resources

Even though my `proguard-project.txt` contains the lines

```
-adaptresourcefilenames    **.png
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.xml
```

and even though `proguard.config` is uncommented in `project.properties` (as mentioned in that file),

running `ant release` on Eclipse's default HelloWorld project still shows within `bin/MainActivity-release.apk` the lines

```
-rw-rw-rw-      9193  17-Jul-2013  14:26:44  res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
-rw-rw-rw-      5057  17-Jul-2013  14:26:44  res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
-rw-rw-rw-     14068  17-Jul-2013  14:26:44  res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png
```

In other words, the name of the png icons is not obfuscated.

What am I missing?

I am not that concerned about proguard handling png filenames correctly, but the fact that this is not working reduces my confidence that the resulting `classes.dex` in the APK has been obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard can handle resources files in the following ways:

- Rename them to follow obfuscated names of corresponding class files (-adaptresourcefilenames),
- Update obfuscated class names in text files (-adaptresourcefilecontents),
- Otherwise, just copy them.

ProGuard doesn't change file extensions or touch the contents of image files, for instance.

Comment: I am also using -adaptresourcefilecontents **.xml (now updated). Should I then not see the png files renamed to something like a.png, b.png, ... with the corresponding xml files also updated?

Comment: im using `-adaptresourcefilenames    **.xsd,**.wsdl,**.xml,**.properties,**.gif,**.jpg,**.png`. Works :)

Comment: I just used the line you suggested and the names of the png files are intact. Are their names changed on your side if you start with Eclipse's HelloWorld project and use only the two changes I mentioned in the question?